# Modify query builder in a Form listener

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have created a custom type like this:

```
private  $selectedCountryId = 0;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $queryBuilder = function (CountryRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.active = 1')
            ->orWhere('c.id = :sid')
            ->orderBy('c.ord', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
            ->setParameter('sid', $this->selectedCountryId)
            ;
        };


    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'query_builder' => $queryBuilder,
        'class' => Country::class,            
    ));
}
public function getParent()
{
    return EntityType::class;
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'CountryType';
}
```

What I am trying to do is to modify the selectedCountryId parameter depending on the instance of an Entity:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData')
    );
}


public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    if ($event->getData() instanceof Country) {
        $this->selectedCountryId = $event->getData()->getId();
    }
}
```

But the setOptions is already called at this stage and I dont't know how to modify query builder here.
Generally what I am trying to achieve is allow given country on the dropdown if it was already stored against given entity (and de-activated later).

Comment: Do you have control over the parent form? can you pass the selected country through an option of this custom type?

Comment: I do but the point is to do that here - I don't want to put same logic to all forms using this type. But I will have to if that's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, you still have one opportunity to modify the query builder on `PRE_SET_DATA` event, because the choice list is not built until the form view is created.

This should do the trick:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        if (null !== $country = $event->getData()) {
            // at this point the option is already resolved 
            // so it'll return the QueryBuilder instance
            $qb = $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOption('query_builder');
            $qb->orWhere('c = :country')->setParameter('country', $country);
        }
    });
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'class' => Country::class,
        'query_builder' => function (CountryRepository $r) {
            return $r->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.active = 1')
                ->orderBy('c.ord', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
            ;
        },
    ]);
}
```

It'll only work for instances of objects.